Is there "enterprise documentation for a tenant"?
I was recently trying to connect in ubuntu my Microsoft 365 (navigate to settings then online accounts), and I received an error after 2FA.
My IT department has asked that I reach out and try to find "enterprise documentation for a tenant" so they can then request on to the Security/Compliance groups for review. Does anyone know where to find this information? This is to try and connect to my MS365 school account.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
GNOME Shell 46.0
Steps:

Open Settings -> Online Accounts -> Microsoft 365 - > enter client ID then "Sign-in".

Click 'sign in..." from window that appears (saying to Sign into Microsoft 365 with browser..).

From browser window that opens 2FA verify identity by choosing Microsoft Authenticator app.

Approve sign-in request numbers appear to enter into phone to authenticate.

Approve and then error appears.




There is not much you can gain by connecting your office 365 with Ubuntu in this manner, since Ubuntu does not (natively) support onedrive. Instead, just sign in with your browser. You can sign in to outlook in Thunderbird as well

There's no such documentation, normally I would see this being "Online Accounts" application that is on the MS365 App Catalog not being added to your tenant.  Unfortunately, it's not possible for us to tell what the name of the corresponding OAuth app is on the MS365 side.  Additionally, this is entirely an MS365 side issue for your tenant, and is really not something Ask Ubuntu can really assist you with.  Note that there is currently no benefits of connecting Online Accounts to MS365 accounts currently.

I was thinking the benefit was to access your OneDrive in your local finder window, in same way when you log into your google account you can access your google drive easily (without having to open browser window.

If you want to set up onedrive, please install the unofficial client (it works!) from https://abraunegg.github.io/
